validity of multiple comparisons
Suppose I have 2 conditions, A and B, and I estimate 10 different metrics in each condition. If I want to test whether each metric is differentiated across the two conditions, do I have to control for multiple comparisons ?

The answer really depends on what kind of type I and type II assertion rates you're willing to stomach -- assuming you're conducting frequentist inference that is. Using $\alpha=0.05$ in an uncorrected analysis (and assuming independence) will give you at least one type I assertion with probability $0.401$, is that acceptable to you?

The metrics are correlated with each other, they  represent different bands of brain activity

In his wonderful book Statistics as Principled Argument, Robert Abelson deals with this sort of "can I?" and "do I have to?" questions very well. He notes that it's not so much what you can do or have to do as what you can justify.  This depends on judgement and thinking and knowledge of your research. Those are good things to require.
You don't have to do significance tests at all, if they don't serve your purpose.  If you do do them, you can adjust for multiple tests (if controlling type I error is key) or not (if controlling type 2 error is more important).
You have to be able to justify your choices; to use your statistical analysis as part of a principled argument (not the whole of it!).
Ronald Fisher, who came up with a lot of this stuff int he early 20th century, was employed for a long time at Rothamsted, where he was testing different fertilizers and other soil treatments. He didn't have strong a priori ideas of which fertilizers were best, or which would work at all. So, controlling type 1 error was key, because, otherwise, he would have no idea which of the things that seemed to work in a sample were "real".
Are you in that situation?
Are you even interested in whether the differences on these metrics are significant? Or do you just care how big they are and how well they are estimated?
I don't know. You do.
Is a type 1 error (saying there's a difference when there isn't) worse than a type 2 error (saying there isn't when there is)? I don't know. You do.
Do you have strong a priori beliefs about differences? I don't know. You do.

I'll add to @Peter's excellent answer that when reporting results you do "have to" state whether you corrected for multiple comparisons (and how)

Of course. You always have to say what you did.
